# Displaying image in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display the image by giving the static path the following way.But the image is not displaying.Could any one please figure out where i went wrong.
The following is my code

```
$("#p").live('click', function (event){var pathname = '';
$("input[type=file]").each(function () {

    var pathname = pathname+$(this).val();
    var f = pathname.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''); 
    alert(f);
    $("#s").attr('src', f);
  });
```

html code

```
 <img style="margin-top:0px; width:2in; height:2in;" id="s" class="imagePreview" />       
 <input type="button" value="Preview" class="k-button" id="p" /> 
 <div id="example" class="k-content"> 
    <div class="configuration k-widget k-header">  
    </div> 
    <form method="post" action="" style="width:45%"> 

    <div> <input name="files" id="files" type="file" onpropertychange="checkimage()"/> 

    <input type="button" value="Submit" class="k-button" id="sub"/> </div> 
    </form> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Flick your HTML man? might take a look,

Comment: <img style="margin-top:0px; width:2in; height:2in;" id="s"   class="imagePreview" /> 

<input type="button" value="Preview" class="k-button" id="p"  />

<div id="example" class="k-content">

<div class="configuration k-widget k-header">

Comment: Hey, cool thanks, so where is input with `type=file`?

Comment: @Tats_innit Hey i included it..forgot to paste it here

Comment: cool, paste it now, with full html I might be able to help you, cheers

Comment: <img style="margin-top:0px; width:2in; height:2in;" id="s"   class="imagePreview" /> 

<input type="button" value="Preview" class="k-button" id="p"  />

<div id="example" class="k-content">

<div class="configuration k-widget k-header">

</div>

<form method="post" action="" style="width:45%">

<div>

<input name="files" id="files" type="file" onpropertychange="checkimage()"/>



<input type="button" value="Submit" class="k-button" id="sub"/>



</div>

</form>

</div>

Comment: @Tats_innit Hey here submit is for saving to DB.i am able to do that.But for previewing before saving am facing problem

Comment: Come on.... edit your question. DON'T paste HTML in comments for God's sake!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are only providing the **src** attribute, you need to **append** it for it to display.

Comment: Well i appended this way..but no luck                  $("<img src=+pathname+ style='margin-top:0px; width:2in; height:2in;' />").appendTo( $("#s"))

Comment: What is your `$("#s")`? In your question you set its source to the pathname, suggesting it is the image element. Now you are appending the new image to that image element? Append it to some container element, like **div** or **p**.

Comment: I am able to get the path in alert box.But the container is not taking the path for displaying

Comment: Your `$("#s")` is probably an image element. Append the image to a **div** or **p**. It must be appended.

Comment: I appended even with "p" no change :(

Comment: The pathname is displaying correctly in alert box, but the image is not being appended. Is the p existing in the page at all, or even with that you are creating it on the fly and not appending to body?

Comment: Yes.. i am having.."p" is the id of the preview button.It can found in the HTML code

Comment: Oh my God, I am not talking about **p** being a **id**! I am talking about **p** being an element! You can't append an image to a button!